# Issue in dynamic model loading in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I am trying to load models dynamically in my controller based on route type. But when I run program I get a message saying "class not found". Here is my code and a link of stackoverflow which I used to fix my issue.

Code:

```
    $model = $this->getModelName($request->matchType);
    $class = "App\Models\$model";
    if($model && class_exists($class))
    {
        $data = $class::where('type_id',$type)->firstOrFail();
    }
    else
    {
        $data = MyModel::find($type);
    }

    return $this->showOne($data);
```

Link:

[Load in models dynamically in Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981766/load-in-models-dynamically-in-laravel-5-1)

This is a good link but not working for me and why simple $model::all() not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double backslashes:

```
$class = "App\\Models\\$model";
```

Try using the `app` helper to resolve the model:

```
$data = app($class)->where('type_id',$type)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: My mistake I was running wrong program for testing. This solution helped me. But I am interested to know the second part too why $class:all(); does not work where class=MyModel. MyModel::all() should work as I have add use MyModel too above in the beginning of file.

Comment: Even though you've imported the class, `$model` is just a string and PHP has no way of making the connection to the import. You should be able to do `app($model)::all()` however.

Answer (score 0):

Add another slash to your class name:

```
 $class = "\App\Models\$model";
```

instead of :

```
 $class = "App\Models\$model";
```

Comment: give more feed back not only its not working do a  `$class = new \App\Models\ModelName; and a dd($class); `